# autocomplete source from json encode

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want the source of autocomplete from array , which the data of the array I retrieve from twig symfony by using json_encode. The problem is I am not sure how to use the array in autocomplete source.

This is my html code :

```
    <div class="form-group required">
                    <input id="autocomplete" name="driver[]" class="form-control" value = "{{place.name}}"/>
    </div>
```

And my javascript is here :

```
    var userlist = {{ lusers| json_encode | raw }};
    var datasource = [{"label" : userlist.name, "value" : userlist.id}];

    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
     source:datasource
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use autocomplete In jquery ui, Your array items should be strings
so you can use this code to convert your array items to strings:

```
for (let i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {
    datasource[] = userlist[i].name;
}
```

but if you want to save id while user select a label, you should use a Select element with search ability.

there are a lot of jquery plugins to do this and it's a good example:

https://select2.org/